# How can I make the Pager of a GridView render outside the table element?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to construct a GridView with pagination, which conforms to WCAG 2.0. The GridView will render an additional row with a cell that has a colspan of the total number of columns of the table and inside that, a sub table. I don't think that conforms to WCAG 2.0, as, in my opinion, the pagination is not part of the data in the table. Therefore, it should not be in a row in the GridView.

Does anybody now a way to take advantage of the functionality of the GridView and still have the Pager outside the table element?

So far, I have found out that I can specify the PagerTempalte, like this (for purpose of showing the mark-up, the pager is not functioning):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>Gridview with pager</h1>
    <asp:GridView ID="CustomerView" DataSourceID="CustomersData" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        AllowPaging="true" runat="server">
        <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Blue" BackColor="LightBlue" />
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" Text="Select a page:" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="PageDropDownList" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CustomersData" SelectCommand="Select [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [Country] From [Customers]"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString%>" runat="server" />
</form>
```

However, this PageTemplate only influences the mark-up of the pager itself. It will still be rendered inside a td of a tr with colspan="number of columns".

Comment: You can Use custom Paging so you have achieve this.

Comment: @Manish Sharma, what do you mean by 'custom paging'? Is this some sort of feature of the gridview, or do you mean, just build it yourself? The latter, can do, of course, but will not give me the advantages of the functionality of the GridView's paging.

Comment: custom Paging means add aspnet pager control and its create paging outside of gridview.
[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28419/A-Basic-ASP-NET-Pager-Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28419/A-Basic-ASP-NET-Pager-Control)

Comment: @Manish Sharma, thanks for supplying a more specific suggestion. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I know it's old, but have you found a good solution?

Comment: @the_lotus, I had to look back in my archive to find the website I was working on at the time. I checked that website and in the end, we didn't change the default mark-up. I suggest you have a go with the solution suggested by Manish Sharma.

Comment: @R.Schreurs thanks a lot for taking the time.